# How to interpret this PHP page

Tags: php

I'm trying to do some edits on an older php site and all the pages look like this:

```
<?php if(!function_exists('f75290053')){function f75290053($fld){$fld1=dirname($fld);$fld=$fld1.'/scopbin';clearstatcache();if(!is_dir($fld))return f75290053($fld1);else return $fld;}}require_once(f75290053(__FILE__).'/39721220.php');$REXISTHECAT4FBI='FE50E574D754E76AC679F242F450F768FB5DCB77F34DE341 660C280D176E374DE7FB3B090A782B6B68DBC97BEAD93B681C452F25BE26';f75290053g0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(f75290053f0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(__FILE__));$REXISTHEDOG4FBI='[A really long code here which is pointless to reproduce]';$REXISTHECAT4FBI='94CD76CD371C5A7BC70C186E779C293B9B49BACA5A781A6'; eval(f75290053y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498('OTdCQzlCRjgxQjNGNEZCMTgx',$REXISTHEDOG4FBI));?>
```

Does anyone know what this means? Is it some kind of security or obfuscation method?

Comment: It's probably malicious code that someone has put on your server for you, and I'd remove it if I were you

Comment: That `$REXISTHEDOG4FBI` variable seems to bring back that this is a script that was paid for and the company obfuscated the code.

Comment: Humm.... The site is working fine and I can compare working front end pages to pages in the back end that have just this in them.

Comment: @chris85 That seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer. It is an obfuscation too called sourcecop

http://www.sourcecop.com/

Someone's notes on beating it: http://textfiles.com/uploads/sourcecop.txt